# Firmar digitalmente un .war en java (eclipse)

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación web java desplegada en un servidor que necesita acceder a las impresoras del sistema, pero no puede. He leído que firmando la aplicación podría solucionarlo, pero sólo encuentro información para firmar un archivo .jar y lo que despliego en el servidor es un .war
Llevo una semana sin poder avanzar con esto...
Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: En teoría debería servir el procedimiento para firmar un jar. ¿Lo has intentado ya?

Comment: sí lo he intentado, en principio hace lo mismo que con un jar pero al desplegar la aplicación de nuevo sigo igual, no tengo acceso a las impresoras, el navegador no me pregunta si confío en este sitio ni nada por el estilo, que es lo que se supone que debería pasar al firmarlo no?

Comment: ¿A qué impresoras quieres acceder?¿A las del propio servidor? No deberías tener que firmar el war para eso.